# Clone elements and load previously loaded scripts

Tags: jquery

I am using clone() to move certain elements into another place in the DOM, but had trouble due to the fact that the scripts previously rendered was not available anymore when called from the cloned elements.

So I think I need to call them again, but one by one will be a PITA. Perhaps getScript will do, but I have no idea to call more than one.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the event handlers for those elements?  Also are you using `.clone(true)`?

Comment: Yes, with .clone(true). I moved a form out of its container div in the main content area, and placed it outside inside the body so it is easily nailed on the page. But all click events are lost there. This seems like when I load things via ajax. Scripts are not retained. $('#system-settings').clone(true).appendTo('body'); Sorry been away for food :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like what I need:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadscript/

**UPDATE:**
Actually when I use append() rather than clone(true), the events handlers are retained.
So there is no need to reload scripts nor clone(), doh :)

The forms actions are not affected so far.